# onFocus function not working properly in Android ?

Tags: android, android-edittext, onfocus

Hi I am newbie in android, I have 3 edit box and I have set 3 setOnFocusChangeListener based on edit box wise, When I focus mobile no edit box ,I am getting sim no id instead mobile no Id. onFocus function getting called with wrong id's. If I did any any mistake please let us know or else solve the solution.

Source code :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_temp);

    objMobileNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
    objSimNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sim_no);
    objImsiNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imsi_no);

    View.OnFocusChangeListener a = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                //this if condition is true when edittext lost focus...
                //check here for number is larger than 10 or not
                //  focusText = "MOBILE";

                // Log.d("BKS", "onFocusChange: " + focusText);
                Log.d("BKS", "onFocusChange: " + view.getId());
                Log.d("BKS", "onFocusChange: " + R.id.mobile_no);



            }

        }
    };

    objMobileNo.setOnFocusChangeListener(a);
    objSimNo.setOnFocusChangeListener(a);
    objImsiNo.setOnFocusChangeListener(a);
```

XML Code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_no"
    style="@style/Material_Action"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_mob_no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sim_no"
    style="@style/Material_Action"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_sim_no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="20" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/imsi_no"
    style="@style/Material_Action"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_imsi_no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="15" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/status"
    style="@style/Material_Action"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/scanning_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mLlayoutBottomButtons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/verify"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Verify"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white">

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Kalanidhi.

Comment: check if(hasFocus) remov ! sign then check it return the current focus textview id

Comment: Thanks ,its working fine..You saved my day :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting same `OnFocusChangeListener` for all `EditText`. so when you focus a new `EditText`, the current one loses its focus. So for both the events `onFocusChange()` will be called. But your `if` condition filters only the view that loses the focus and not the one which got the focus.

So replace

```
if (!hasFocus) {

}
```

with this to make it work as expected

```
if (hasFocus) {

}
```